# How to wrap first HTML attribute in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I want PhpStorm to wrap all HTML attributes, as explained in the Vue docs.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-attribute-elements-strongly-recommended

I found the settings to wrap all other attributes, but it's keep the first one next to the opening tag.
[image]

These are my current wrapping settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is found a little lower in the same settings panel
**New line before first attribute:**

[image]